# Compute the order of the group U(13)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Preparing for my first abstract exam and trying to make sure I completely understand computing order of groups as we focused only on the proof rather than computations. An example given was "compute the order of the group $U(13)$"

Do I start by listing out all the elements and then just count them?

Any help with the computation of problems like these is appreciated.

Comment: What is the definition of $U(13)$?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** $13$ is prime and $$\lvert U(n)\rvert=\varphi(n)$$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$, where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function.

Comment: Ah, so I suppose $U(n)=(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^\times$?

Comment: Essentially, yeah, @HagenvonEitzen. The isomorphism I was thinking of in my now-deleted comment was $$\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)\cong U(n).$$